# Host Application With Embedded Mongoose Server

Tags: c++, c, mongoose-web-server, embedded-server

I have created a standalone exe to provide some REST APIs using embedded mongoose server [ official C version ].
It works fine on my machine on localhost.
Now my plan is to run this application on a server from where client applications can use it. But can't make it work across machines.It only works on the machine it is running with localhost url. I am using port 5554. Is there any setting in mongoose server to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Set listening URL to `http://0.0.0.0:PORT`. Binding to `0.0.0.0` would accept connections from anywhere. Binding to `localhost` (or, to `127.0.0.1` which is the same this) would accept connection only from your local workstation.

See https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose/tree/master/examples/http-restful-server